# Submitting build to iTunes Connect confusion

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have my developer and distribution certificate and I validated my app. But now in Xcode -> Window -> Organizer, it says *SUBMIT* under *VALIDATE*. I click *SUBMIT* and it states

> "To submit to the iOS Apple Store, select a development team"

I don't want to submit to app store for review yet, I just want to upload my build into iTunes Connect. I thought I do it through Xcode but I can't find anywhere that states to submit to iTunes Connect.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the same thing. You select "submit to the iOS App Store" to submit to iTunes Connect.

Apple has not updated the text in Xcode to reflect that change presumably because the package is packaged for the iOS App Store.

Answer (score 0):

Submitting the app to the iOS App Store is the same with uploading the binary to iTunes Connect. You should not be worried about it since the app will only be submitted for review once you click the 'Submit for Review' button in the app's iTunes Connect page.